# Session cookie in different browsers with a wrong client time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

There is a problem with cookie. I have an ARM device with not good battery - so time on this device may be wrong - it can be in a future or in a past. Lighttpd works on device and there is an app wrote on CodeIgniter framework (php). For saving an autorization I use a standart system library Sessions and Cookie helper. Expiration time for cookie is 2 hours. And here is my problem:
when device is in a future, more than in 2 hours, Chrome and Firefox on client can't autorize (they think cookie already expired and can't save a session), but Opera can and work well.
Do you know a way to make it work independently from both time settings on server and on client?

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: It is Angstrom embedded linux.

Answer (score 0):

What I made to solve this problem:
Set cookie's expire attribute to zero, but leave expire check on server side. 
Autorization works well, cookies don't waste browsers storage and session live for a time which I set in the application.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to configure your server to use a Network Time Protocol.

Linux machines are well known to be incapable of keeping track of time by themselves and therefore to keep your time in sync it's advised to sync the time from an NTP server.

Although I'm not particularly familiar with Angstrom, I believe the following instructions should work:

To install NTP on your server (if you don't already have it installed):

```
opkg update
opkg list|grep ntp
opkg install ntp
```

You then need to configure your NTP configuration file (located in **/etc/ntp.conf**) to use an NTP server.

Locate a relevant server, I normally use http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/ and select the timezone on the right, you will be provided with many servers you can use.

Edit your **/etc/ntp.conf** file and add the server addresses, prefixed with `server` so that your config file looks similiar to:

```
# This is the most basic ntp configuration file
# The driftfile must remain in a place specific to this
# machine - it records the machine specific clock error

driftfile /etc/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntpd.log

# BELOW IS WHERE YOU ADD YOUR SERVER RECORDS #

# NTP Servers for Ireland from www.pool.ntp.org
server server.address.1
server server.address.2
server server.address.3
server server.address.4

# Using local hardware clock as fallback
# Disable this when using ntpd -q -g -x as ntpdate or it will sync to itself
# server 127.127.1.0 
# fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14

# Defining a default security setting
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap
```

Start up your NTP services and you should be in sync with the rest of the world...

```
systemctl enable ntpdate.service
systemctl enable ntpd.service
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but there is a small moment: it's a local network device hence there is no internet connection.

Comment: Problem solved. Solution is in my answer. Thanks for participating.